# Search from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

This is the `array` where I want to search

```
$contacts =array(
array( "name"=>"Samatha Perera", "Email"=>"smatha@gmail.com", "Telephone"=>array("office"=>"0112233789","personal"=>"0718256385","home"=>"0112843425")),
array( "name"=>"Charith Fernando", "Email"=>"charith@gmail.com", "Telephone"=>array("office"=>"0112656457","personal"=>"0718456723","home"=>"0112334466")),
array( "name"=>"Malith Wijekoon", "Email"=>"malith@hotmail.com", "Telephone"=>array("office"=>"0332301311","personal"=>"077456453","home"=>"0112556677")),
array( "name"=>"Sanath Perera", "Email"=>"sanath@yahoo.com", "Telephone"=>array("office"=>"0112201654","personal"=>"0757277365","home"=>"0312867725")),
array( "name"=>"Gihan Indran", "Email"=>"gihan@gmail.com", "Telephone"=>array("office"=>"032222526","personal"=>"0778856385","home"=>"0322243426")),
    );
```

Form will look like this

Search By : **Name** or **Email** or **Telephone** (This is a combo box)

Search Value : _______________ (Search Button)

I want to search and display the results in table as follows.

```
-----------------------------------
Name              | Email                  | Telephone


Samatha Perera       smatha@gmail.com         Office:0112233789

                                              Personal:0718256385

                                              Home:0112843425
```

Comment: And what do you expect from us?

Comment: who deleted the question?

Comment: i want to search from that array

Comment: We are busy people. We are here to help those who seek to learn. We are not here to do the work for those too lazy to learn. Show some effort and we will show some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.... bellow code will match any text....

```
//$search = 'Samatha';
//$search = '011';
$search = 'Ferna';

$match = array();
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Email</td>
<td>Phone</td>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($contacts as $key => $value) {

    if(strpos($value['name'],$search) !== false || strpos($value['Email'],$search) !== false) {
        $match[] = $value;
        continue;
    }

    foreach($value['Telephone'] as $k => $v) {
        if(strpos($v,$search) !== false) {
            $match[] = $value;
            break;
        }
    }


}
if(!empty($match))
foreach($match as $key => $value) {
    ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $value['name']?></td>
<td><?php echo $value['Email']?></td>
<td><?php 
foreach($value['Telephone'] as $k => $v) {
    echo "{$k} : {$v}<br />";
}
?></td>
</tr>
    <?php
}
?></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the way I see it, you're going to need to loop through each array and compare the values.

```
//$search_term = 'Samatha Perera';
$search_term = '032222526';

foreach ($contacts AS $record) {


    foreach ($record AS $key => $val) {

        $match_found = false;
        if ($key == 'Telephone') {

            if (in_array($search_term, $record['Telephone'])) {
                $match_found = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (preg_match('/'.$search_term.'/i', $val)) {
                $match_found = true;
            }
        }

        if ($match_found) {

            $name_length = strlen($record['name']);
            $email_length = strlen($record['Email']);
            $total_pad = $name_length + $email_length + 6;

            print "\n".$record['name'].' | '.$record['Email'].' | '.$record['Telephone']['office']."\n\n".
                                                         str_pad(' ', $total_pad, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT).$record['Telephone']['personal']."\n\n".
                                                         str_pad(' ', $total_pad, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT).$record['Telephone']['home']."\n";
        }
    }

}
```